# How to add XML namespace prefix in XML response of REST API in Spring Boot?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

We have RESTful service developed using Spring Boot. We want to return XML response with namespace prefix.

**PersonsController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonsController {

    @GetMapping
    public @ResponseBody Person getPerson() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Jon");
        person.setLastName("Doe");

        return person;
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "person", namespace = "abc.net/")
public class Person {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "abc.net/")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(namespace = "abc.net/")
    private String lastName;
}
```

**Expected response:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:person xmlns:ns2="abc.net/">
    <ns2:firstName>Jon</firstName>
    <ns2:lastName>Doe</lastName>
</ns2:person>
```

**Actual response:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<person xmlns="abc.net/">
    <firstName>Jon</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
</person>
```

**MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter bean creation**

```
@Bean
    MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter getMappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter() {

        JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbAnnotationModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
        mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(xmlMapper);


        mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(jaxbAnnotationModule);
        return mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;
    }
```

I tried putting `@XmlSchema` in `package-info.java` component at the package level with required prefix & namespaceURI, but no luck.

How can I configure the Spring Boot XML marshaller to include adding of namespace prefix in XML response - as mentioned in the expected response above?

We are using Spring Boot version: 2.6.6.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` instead of `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`. Bean creation snapshot below,

```
@Bean
    public Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter() { return new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter(); }
```

Seems like we need to use Jaxb convertor instead of Jackson.